# How do encrypt and decrypt file using gpg in emacs using passphrase?

Tags: mu4e, gpg, authinfo

Hope all is well.

I am setting up mu4e on emacs and I got but when I try to send an email I cant because my `.authinfo.gpg` is not being decrypted. it  says that it cant find the key.

But I remember trying to encrypt an `.authinfo` file within emacs but couldnt so I used my terminal and I did this:

```
gpg -c .authinfo
```

And I entered the passphrase.

So now I want to use this passphrase to decrypt my file but I dont know how I can get emacs to see this passphrase and How to configure.

I have tried searching through google to find my answer but cant find it.

thanks

Comment: Does it work with magic comment like `;; -*- epa-file-encrypt-to: nil -*-`? [Emacs manual: 3.6 Encrypting/decrypting gpg files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/epa/Encrypting_002fdecrypting-gpg-files.html#index-epa_002dfile_002dselect_002dkeys-43)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was able to send my email with mu4e and this is how I made it work.

In my `.authinfo.gpg` file added this to the top of the file:

```
# -*- epa-file-encrypt-to: ("kramer@example.com") -*-
```

But I also had to generate a gpg key and once you  do emacs is smart to know the key.

to generate the key do this:

```
gpg --gen-key
gpg --armor --export-secret-keys <email> > mykey.asc
```

and to encrypt your file - in my case `.authinfo` do:

```
gpg -c file1.txt
```